# How to merge all dictionary items with common values in python

Tags: python

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Column1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
     'Column2': [['tango', 'bravo', 'alpha'], ['bravo', 'test'], ['romero', 'test'], ['delta']]
    })
print(df)

  Column1                Column2
0       A  [tango, bravo, alpha]
1       B          [bravo, test]
2       C         [romero, test]
3       D                [delta]
```

I converted the df to a dict like this:

```
d = {'A': ['tango', 'bravo', 'alpha'],
     'B': ['bravo', 'test'],
     'C': ['romero', 'test'],
     'D': ['delta']}
```

What I want is to merge all rows (values and keys) that have a common value, which in my case would result in the following dictionary:

```
d = {"A , B , C": {"tango", "bravo", "alpha" , "bravo", "test", "romero"},
     "D": {"delta"}}
```

This task can be done in the df with pandas or as dictionary, I don't know which one is easier.

Comment: @mmdanziger Both are valid, when I paste them into VScode and print a value and type.

Comment: I just expect to merge all elements that have a common value which in my case here is "bravo" and to merge the keys and the values into one string separated by a ','. As for the valid dictionary format, isn't it D = { Key1 : Value1 , Key2 : Value2}? With the keys and values as strings.

Comment: @Gab, what would be the expected result if `"C": {"romero", "test"}`?

Comment: D = {'A , B , C': {"tango, bravo, alpha , bravo, test , romero, test"}} basically if there's a common value between two elements it merges them

Comment: At this point, I'm thinking of ditching the dictionary altogether and putting them in a list of lists. Would it be easier?

Comment: Just to be clear, your dict values are sets with always one big string?

Comment: I actually have a list in the following format [String][Array of strings] but I transformed it into a dictionary thinking it would be easier. Well i guess I was wrong

Comment: maybe add the state of the data before you made a dictionary of it. Let's see if that is easier then.

Comment: I edited the post and added the initial state of my data.

Comment: That's different from your dictionary. In the dataframe you have a list of strings, in the dictionary you have one "list-like" string in a set. Sure thats not just a format mistake when posting the question here? It shoud be `'A': {"tango", "bravo", "alpha"}`right?

Comment: Yes, I joined the strings in the dictionary because I couldn't append them inside the dictionary for some reason. I got an error telling me that str doesn't have the append functionality so I just joined them with a ','

Comment: converting your dataframe to a dictionary could be easily done like this: `df.set_index('Column1')['Column2'].to_dict()`

Comment: What if I have `{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 3], 'c': [3, 4]}`? Should all three keys be merged, even though `a` and `c` have no keys in common? Should we group `a` with `b` on the basis of the common `2` value, and leave `c` out? Or the other way around? In the latter cases, how do we decide which way to group them?

Comment: check the 4th comment. OP said that in that case, all keys (a,b and c) should be merged.

Comment: Both solutions worked! Thank youu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is deceptively complex because you may have to merge an arbitrary number of dict items based on a pairwise comparison. I was not able to solve it with a punchy one-liner with `itertools` and had to actually articulate the algorithm old-school:

```py
# let's get a slightly more interesting input, in a more amenable datatype
D = {
    "A": ["tango", "bravo", "alpha"],
    "B": ["bravo", "test"],
    "C": ["romero", "test"],
    "D": ["other"],
    "E": ["and", "other"],
    "F": ["loner"],
}

queue, outqueue = list(D.items()), []
while queue:
    k, v = queue.pop(0)
    shares_values = False
    for idx, [otherk, otherv] in enumerate(queue):
        if not shares_values and set(v) & set(otherv):
            queue.pop(idx) #don't keep re-adding the match
            shares_values = True
            newk = f"{k}, {otherk}"
            newv = v + otherv
            queue.insert(0, (newk, newv)) #at 0 so order is respected
            break
    if not shares_values:
        outqueue.append((k, v))
outdict = dict(outqueue)
assert outdict == {
    "A, B, C": ["tango", "bravo", "alpha", "bravo", "test", "romero", "test"],
    "D, E": ["other", "and", "other"],
    "F": ["loner"],
}
```

There may be some kind of `itertools` or `DataFrame.groupby.agg` magic that could solve this problem but given that the solution will always require an arbitrary number of passes over the item list, you may be better off using an explicit queue processing approach like the one I've shown here.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with [`networkx.Graph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/graph.html#networkx.Graph) and [`networkx.connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components).

Using the same input as @mmdanziger since it covers more possible outcomes for your rules.

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

d = {
    "A": ["tango", "bravo", "alpha"],
    "B": ["bravo", "test"],
    "C": ["romero", "test"],
    "D": ["other"],
    "E": ["and", "other"],
    "F": ["loner"],
}

#build combination of all keys pairwise
#check for common values in the list
G = nx.Graph()
for nodes in itertools.combinations(d.keys(), r=2):
    common_edges = set(d[nodes[0]]) & set(d[nodes[1]])
    for edge in common_edges:
        G.add_edge(*nodes, value=edge)

# get list with all connected keys (keys which have any common value)
connected = list(nx.connected_components(G))
print(connected)
# [{'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E'}]

# create new dict from "connected" with joined keys and joined values
new_dict = {}
for groups in connected:
    res = set()
    for key in groups:
        res.update(d[key])
    new_dict[f"{' , '.join(list(groups))}"] = res

# check for elements in the original dictionary which aren't connected to anything and add them
for k,v in d.items():
    if not any([k in key for key in new_dict.keys()]):
        new_dict[k] = d[k]

print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'A , B , C': {'alpha', 'bravo', 'romero', 'tango', 'test'},
 'D , E': {'and', 'other'},
 'F': ['loner']}
```